# Indexing by text instead of numbers in bibiliography in texlipse

Tags: indexing, texlipse

How to get bibiliography indexed, not by numbers, by some given letters?. I want to refer to the book by a pneumonic, so that in the output file I would get, for example [AB], instead of some number, for instance [3], automatically given by texlipse. Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Note, in particular, that your question currently seems to confuse a bibliography with an index and that we need to know how you are currently generating citations and references.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, it is not clear what you are asking. Note that the list of sources printed at the end of a document is not the same as an index. If I am right that you really mean the bibliography, please edit the tags for your question appropriately.

Here is one way of generating a bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}

\autocite{baez/article}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Numeric style]

I suspect this is what you are referring to. If so, then, depending on how you generate your reference list, you just need to change the style. For example, the above could be changed from the default `numeric` to `alphabetic`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}

\autocite{baez/article}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

which is closer to what I think you may want:

[image: Alphabetic]